# Proving an inequality using calculus

Tags: calculus, inequality

I was going over a solution recently, which lays out a subtle argument. I believe that it is not rigorous enough.
The inequality is given below:-

$\cos(x)\gt \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for all $x$ belonging to the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$.

The solution argued that the concavity of both the functions is opposite, that is one function is concave up whereas the other function is concave down.
However I was not satisfied by this approach. Could anyone give a better approach or explain this argument more rigorously.

Thank You.

Comment: But at $x=0$ we have $\cos 0 = 1 $ and $\frac{1}{0^2 +1 } =1$. The problem should be this $\cos x \geq \frac{1}{x^2 +1}$

Comment: You can try to show $\cos(x)\geq 1-x^2/2$ for $x\in [0,1]$  and then $1-x^2/2\geq 1/(1+x^2)$ if $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Note that $\cos x$ and $1/(1+x^2)$ both have a *maximum* at $x=0$, hence both are concave down there.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can establish the inequality without appealing to calculus.  Recall from geometry that $\sin x\le x$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2$.

This inequality is equivalent to the inequalities

$$\begin{align}
\sin^2x&\le x^2\\\\
1-\cos^2x&\le x^2\\\\
\cos^2x&\ge 1-x^2\tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

For $0\le x\le 1$, we may take the square root of both sides of $(1)$ and write

$$\cos x\ge \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Next, it is easy to show that for $0\le x\le \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}>\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  This is left as an exercise.

Therefore, for $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{4}$, we have the desired inequality

$$\cos x\ge \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

---

**Using Calculus**

From the extended law of the mean, there exists a number $0<\xi<x$ such that $\cos x=1-\frac12 \cos (\xi)x^2$.

Since $|\cos \xi|\le 1$, we see that $\cos x\ge 1-\frac12 x^2$.

It is easy to show that for $|x|\le 1$, $1-\frac12 x^2\ge \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, whence we have the desired inequality again!

---

**SIDE NOTE:**

As an interesting side note, we also have from geometry the inequality $\sin x\ge x\cos x$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2$.  From this, it is easy to show that

$$\cos x\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to get the inequality without using any calculus.

For clarity of exposition, it is convenient to rewrite the desired inequality as $(1+\theta^2)\cos\theta\gt1$ for $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/4$.

Draw the unit circle and draw an angle $\theta$ in the first quadrant, so that $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$.  Measured in radians, $\theta$ is the arc length along the circle from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, which is greater than the length of the chord connecting the same two points.  This inequality can be written as

$$\theta^2\gt(1-\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2$$

Expanding this and using the trig identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, we can conclude

$$1+\theta^2\gt3-2\cos\theta$$

for all $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$.  Hence to prove the desired inequality, it suffices to show that $(3-2\cos\theta)\cos\theta\gt1$ for $0\lt\theta\le\pi/4$.  But this can be rewritten as $0\gt1-3\cos\theta+2\cos^2\theta$ or, in factored form, as

$$0\gt(1-\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)$$

This is clearly satisfied when $1\gt\cos\theta\gt1/2$, which is to say when $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/3$.  Since $\pi/4\lt\pi/3$, we have the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I am tempted to approach this problem by using what's called the "Racetrack principle". It can be proved using the Mean Value Theorem. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_principle

Statement: Let $f,g$ be continuously differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.If, $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f^{'}(x)>g^{'}(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$.

A proof of this result can be written by taking $h=f-g$ and applying the Mean Value Theorem to it.

Before we proceed, I hope you're familiar with the following inequality: $Sin(x)<x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Take $f(x)=Cos(x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$. $f(0)=g(0)=1$. What we now need to show is that the function $H(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ has positive derivative.

We get $f^{'}(x)= -Sin(x)$ and $g^{'}(x)= \frac{-2x}{1+x^{2}}$. So,
\begin{equation}
Sin(x)<x \implies -Sin(x)>-x \\
\implies H^{'}(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}-Sin(x)>\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}-x\\
\end{equation}
On $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ , $x(\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}-x)>0$. So, $H^{'}(x)>0$ and we can apply the result to show the desired inequality.